# How to make SirfStar IV chip operate as I2C slave only?

Tags: i2c, gps

I bought a GPS that has SirfStar GSD4e chipset inside.
I see with the logic analyser that when in I2C mode it is writing to the bus.
I understand by that that it is in master mode.
**How can I make it an I2C slave?**

In case it is needed the GPS is Maestro Wireless A2235-H.
But I think this implies in every Sirf based GPS module...

Answer (score 2):

It does not look like this chip set supports talking to the chip as an I2C slave.

Page 22 of the [A2235-H User manual](http://update.maestro-wireless.com/Technical%20Documentation/GPS%20Line/A2235-H/Maestro_GPS_Receiver_A2235_H_User_Manual_V1.3.pdf) shows all of the pin functions.

Pins 17 and 18 are used as an I2C interface for the GPS module to talk to en external MEMs sensor for some level of IMU functionality.

Pins 14 and 22 are the I2C interface for the module to talk to a slave EEPROM device for saving non-volatile data, operating as a stand alone HOST MODE.

It looks like user communication with the GPS module is limited to the UART or SPI interfaces.

Comment: I am also looking to control this device with I2C. I don't see a way to do it looking at the data sheet BUT it makes no sense that its a I2C bus master as pin 11 is an INPUT. SCL for a master is always an output so I will need to contact the manufacture of the part for further clarification. I also do not see a way to specify an I2C address range for the device. The data sheet does not say what address it would respond to if it was a slave either.